# Swing - How to add Crtl + JButton click

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I want to add a shortcut option of using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key + `JButton` click using the mouse on a simple calculator. I know how to input <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> using `KeyStroke` but I don't know how to do it with a `JButton` click using mouse.
Here is what I have:

```
private void displayCopyRight() {
    buttons[13].setAction(new AbstractAction("" + button_Shapes[13]) {
        {
            putValue(Action.ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, getValue(Action.NAME));
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            display.setText("[c] Khoa-Nguyen");
        }
    });

    int c = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
    KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
    buttons[13].getInputMap(c).put(ks, button_Shapes[13]);
    buttons[13].getActionMap().put(button_Shapes[13], buttons[13].getAction());        
}
```

This only binds the Ctrl + letter C on keyboard together. What I want to do is bind Ctrl + JButton click using the mouse. The buttons[13] is letter C as a JButton. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please, visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Read some docs, tutorials and/or blogs and then provide some code showing what you attempted to do and what your problem in the code is.

Comment: Use global keybindings or a key listener to toggle a public boolean variable when "Ctrl" is pressed, then inside your action/click event, you can just check if that boolean variable to see if it is true or false and act accordingly.

Comment: `I want to add a shortcut option of using the Ctrl key + JButton click ` -That is not a shortcut. Ctrl-C is a shortcut for the keyboard because the button doesn't need to have focus.  Ctrl-Click on a button is not a shortcut because the button needs to be clicked anyway, so why force the user to hold down the Ctrl key as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try checking modifiers property of ActionEvent. It is a mask field If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is held then the modifiers field can be tested for ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
   if ((ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK & e.getModifiers()) != 0){
      // Do your action here
   }
}
```